# elif a=="no": ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

this is the error i get for my code I cant seem to find out how to fix it

```
File "C:\Users\mayar\Desktop\final edge project\execute_html.py", line 19
    elif a=="no":
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Code -

```
import codecs
import subprocess
import os

while (True):
    corona = input("Do you want to know more about Coronavirus-COVID-19?                                                             answer in yes/no format \n")
    if corona== "yes":
        url = "CORONAVIRUS.htm"
#Python executes code following the try statement as a “normal” part of the program
    try:
        os.startfile(url)
#The code that follows the except statement is the program’s response to any exceptions in the preceding try clause.
    except AttributeError:
        try:
                subprocess.call(['open', url])
        except:
                print('Could not open URL')
        break
    elif a=="no":
       print("Have a nice day!")
    else:
        print("Enter either yes/no")
```

Comment: I have a feeling your indentation is wrong, can you edit your question to include indentation? Also, putting three backslashes (`) before and after your code will mark it as code.

Comment: i added a picture does that help because when I edit the text here it shows that it's indented but when I post it doesn't work

Comment: You need to indent the try end except statements and the code inside them to be inside the if statement.

Comment: NO! there is something wrong in your code. what is the `a` variable? you should check `corona` like this: `elif corona == "no"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `elif` directly after `if`. You can't have any other lines of codes between an if and the following `elif`s. You are probably messing up with the indentations in your code. You can edit your code to have `try except` to be included inside the first `if` statement and then it will work.

Correct code -

```
import codecs
import subprocess
import os

while (True):
    corona = input("Do you want to know more about Coronavirus-COVID-19?                                                             answer in yes/no format \n")
    if corona== "yes":
        url = "CORONAVIRUS.htm"

        try:
            os.startfile(url)
    #The code that follows the except statement is the program’s response to any exceptions in the preceding try clause.
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                    subprocess.call(['open', url])
            except:
                    print('Could not open URL')
            break
    elif corona=="no":
       print("Have a nice day!")
    else:
        print("Enter either yes/no")
```

Comment: Or you can put the try statement inside of the if statement, right? That is why I asked for the indentation.

Comment: @KrishnanShankar Yea ! right, I thought he was trying `try except` outside if only to realise it was indentation mistake

Comment: Hi @Abhishek help with my question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63033154/how-to-make-program-repeat-what-it-just-said-in-pyttsx3-with-python/63033998?noredirect=1#comment111469483_63033998

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
import codecs
import subprocess
import os

while (True):
    corona = input("Do you want to know more about Coronavirus-COVID-19?                                                             answer in yes/no format \n")
    if corona== "yes":
        url = "CORONAVIRUS.htm"
#Python executes code following the try statement as a “normal” part of the program
        try:
            os.startfile(url)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                subprocess.call(['open', URL])
            except:
                print('Could not open URL')
                break
    elif corona=="no":
       print("Have a nice day!")
    else:
        print("Enter either yes/no")
```

Answer (score 0):

Right code:

```
import codecs
import subprocess
import os

url = "CORONAVIRUS.htm"
while True:
    corona = input("Do you want to know more about Coronavirus-COVID-19?                                                             answer in yes/no format \n")
    if corona== "yes":
#Python executes code following the try statement as a “normal” part of the program
        try:
            os.startfile(url)
    #The code that follows the except statement is the program’s response to any exceptions in the preceding try clause.
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                    subprocess.call(['open', url])
            except:
                    print('Could not open URL')
            break
    elif corona=="no":
       print("Have a nice day!")
    else:
        print("Enter either yes/no")
```